# Non positive semi-definiteness error when creating time series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels

I am receiving an error when I try to fit some data I have to a VAR Time series model in Python via `statsmodels`, the documentation of which is available [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#var):

The data I have is available in a dataframe `df_IBM_training` which can be seen below:

```
          date  sym    open      high       low     close  newscount  
6   2014.08.05  IBM  189.30  189.3000  186.4100  187.0800          4   
9   2014.08.06  IBM  185.80  186.8800  184.4400  185.9000          0   
12  2014.08.07  IBM  186.56  186.8800    1.0000  184.2800          2   
15  2014.08.08  IBM  183.32  186.6800  183.3200  186.5499         18
```

The model VAR I want to build looks like this, the regressors of which I try to create in the code below. I also try to search for the ideal model order in the code below, which is where I get the error. Each coefficient in the equation below, examples include α1,1, γ1,11 is associated with a `regressor` in the code:

```
Δlog(C_t) =  α1,1(log(C_t - 1) − log(O_t-1))
           + α1,2(log‌​(C_t - 1) − log(H_t-1))
           + α1,3(log(C_t - 1) − log(L_t-1))
           + γ1,11Δlog(C_t − 1)
           + γ1,12Δlog(O_t − 1)
           + γ1,13Δlog(H_t − 1)
           + γ1,14Δlog(L_t − 1)
           + εt
```

My code is as follows. For some reason, I get the following error in the line `model.select_order(8)`:

> numpy.linalg.linalg.linalgerror 7-th leading minor not positive semi-definite

```
#VAR regressors
df_IBM_training['log_ret0'] = np.log(df_IBM_training.close) - np.log(df_IBM_training.close.shift(1)) 
df_IBM_training['log_ret1'] = np.log(df_IBM_training.open) - np.log(df_IBM_training.open.shift(1)) 
df_IBM_training['log_ret2'] = np.log(df_IBM_training.high) - np.log(df_IBM_training.high.shift(1)) 
df_IBM_training['log_ret3'] = np.log(df_IBM_training.low) - np.log(df_IBM_training.low.shift(1)) 
df_IBM_training = df_IBM_training[np.isfinite(df_IBM_training['log_ret3'])]

regressor_1 = np.log(df_IBM_training['close']) - np.log(df_IBM_training['open'])
regressor_2 = np.log(df_IBM_training['close']) - np.log(df_IBM_training['high'])
regressor_3 = np.log(df_IBM_training['close']) - np.log(df_IBM_training['low'])
regressor_4 = df_IBM_training['log_ret0']
regressor_5 = df_IBM_training['log_ret1']
regressor_6 = df_IBM_training['log_ret2']
regressor_7 = df_IBM_training['log_ret3']

X_IBM = [regressor_1, regressor_2, regressor_3, regressor_4,regressor_5, regressor_6, regressor_7]
X_IBM = np.array(X_IBM)
X_IBM = X_IBM.T

model = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(X_IBM)

#The line below is where the error arises
model.select_order(8)
```

**Edit**: Traceback Error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TimeSeries.py", line 70, in <module>
    model.select_order(8)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py", line 505, in select_order
    for k, v in iteritems(result.info_criteria):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py", line 35, in __getattribute__
    obj = getattr(results, attr)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\decorators.py", line 94, in __get__
    _cachedval = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py", line 1468, in info_criteria
    ld = logdet_symm(self.sigma_u_mle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\linalg.py", line 213, in logdet_symm
    c, _ = linalg.cho_factor(m, lower=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_cholesky.py", line 132, in cho_factor
    check_finite=check_finite)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_cholesky.py", line 30, in _cholesky
    raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor not positive definite" % info)
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 5-th leading minor not positive definite
```

Comment: What's your sample size? You are estimating 8*7 + 1 parameters per equation, 7 times that in total. Also, Python provides nice tracebacks. You need to show at least the last few lines, preferably all, to even see where the exception has been raised. I don't have a guess for the specific linalgerror because I've never seen it before.

Comment: If it's possible to identify why the linalg error is raised, then it would be useful to provide a better exception or exception message. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/new for opening an issue.

Comment: @user333700 My sample size is only 65 data points. I am actually estimating only 7 parameters from what I can tell-α1,1, to γ1,14 (as can be seen in the equation  in my question) for each time t. I have also edited the question to show the traceback error.

Comment: But you are calling `select_order` with `maxlags=8`, which means it tries to find the best model for up to 8 lags. VAR with 8 lags has 8*7 lag parameters + constant for each equation, and we lose maxlags observations for the initial conditions. If you only want to estimate the model with 1 lag, then don't use `select_order`. The actual exception is in the loglikelihood calculation for the information criterion, which would mean that it managed to estimate the parameters, I think.

Comment: @user333700 Thank you. However, I got rid of this line and I still have a non-positive semi-definiteness issue associated with one of the minors when I add the lines `results = model.fit(1)
results.summary()
results.plot()` instead. The error arises in the line `results.summary()` and basically has a very similar traceback error as last time.

Comment: The covariance of the estimated errors is not positive definite, which is required because it uses Cholesky decomposition, and there is no protection if it's singular. My guess is that the close relationship between C O H L and the short time series causes a reduced rank, (almost) perfectly collinear residuals. If you post a reproducible example to the pystatsmodels mailing list or issue tracker, then I look into it, and see if we can add support for singular covariance matrix.

Comment: What I think is that the collinearity comes from an accounting identity between the levels and changes of C O H L, but I cannot figure out right now how closely they are satisfied by your VAR.

Comment: @user333700 Thank you for the help. I guess there is now way for me to proceed ahead currently then, unless I consider a different model completely or do think there is a possible mathematical fix to having perfectly collinear residuals?

Comment: There would be a numerical fix, force the covariance to be positive semidefinite and use SVD or eigenvalue decomposition instead of Cholesky. It might also be possible to use other kinds of penalization to get a numerical solution. However, I don't know whether it makes "statistical sense". It will also depend on what you want. You will not have a non-singular error decomposition, and inference might have to be done carefully, but I wouldn't expect problems in prediction for example, if the parameter estimates look good enough.